# Heroku fails to deploy | neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: python, github, heroku, deployment

I'm encountering some errors when I want to deploy my model to heroku. It is said that neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found and I don't have any idea how to fix this.

```
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     
 !     A Python security update is available! Upgrade as soon as possible to: python-3.10.7
 !     See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
 !     
-----> Installing python-3.10.4
-----> Installing pip 22.2.2, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Obtaining slim from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/models@487c4b2a13a4b34f3b6b0ac5715b05e275306853#egg=slim&subdirectory=researchslim (from -r /tmp/build_36246477/requirements.txt (line 82))
         Cloning https://github.com/tensorflow/models (to revision 487c4b2a13a4b34f3b6b0ac5715b05e275306853) to /app/.heroku/src/slim
         Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models /app/.heroku/src/slim
         Running command git rev-parse -q --verify 'sha^487c4b2a13a4b34f3b6b0ac5715b05e275306853'
         Running command git fetch -q https://github.com/tensorflow/models 487c4b2a13a4b34f3b6b0ac5715b05e275306853
         Running command git checkout -q 487c4b2a13a4b34f3b6b0ac5715b05e275306853
         Resolved https://github.com/tensorflow/models to commit 487c4b2a13a4b34f3b6b0ac5715b05e275306853
       ERROR: slim from git+https://github.com/tensorflow/models@487c4b2a13a4b34f3b6b0ac5715b05e275306853#egg=slim&subdirectory=researchslim (from -r /tmp/build_36246477/requirements.txt (line 82)) does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't build pip package from [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) main directory. Check [installation process](https://github.com/tensorflow/models#installation)